# Can't expand oVirt VM disk to new size with neither LVM or resize2fs

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ovirt

I have a oVirt server with a VM, the VM was created with a 20GB disk but that quickly ran out of space so I added another 20GB to it and now I'm trying to expand the disk.

I have done this once before on an old VM and then I ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo lvm
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 4.00 GiB (1024 extents) to <49.00 GiB (12543 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
lvm> exit
  Exiting.



$ sudo lvm
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 4.00 GiB (1024 extents) to <49.00 GiB (12543 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
lvm> exit
  Exiting.
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 7
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 12844032 (4k) blocks long.
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               949M     0  949M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              199M  1.2M  198M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   49G  3.8G   43G   9% /
tmpfs                              993M     0  993M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              993M     0  993M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  107M  803M  12% /boot
/dev/loop0                          28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2                          69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/14804
/dev/loop3                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12159
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1026
/dev/loop6                          67M   67M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20840
tmpfs                              199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/1000
```

And that expanded the disk but now for some reason on my new VM these commands does not work and I get the following output:

```
$ sudo lvm
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  New size (4863 extents) matches existing size (4863 extents).
lvm>



$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 4979712 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Looking into `fdisk -l` I have the following:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 54.97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.45 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.79 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 68.26 MiB, 71573504 bytes, 139792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 68.17 MiB, 71475200 bytes, 139600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 27.9 MiB, 28405760 bytes, 55480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 40 GiB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EFA99D35-85DD-4D0D-A4DE-19514BF6AE89

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096  2101247  2097152   1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 41940991 39839744  19G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 18.102 GiB, 20396900352 bytes, 39837696                                                                                                              sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: The device shows up as 49GB, which doesn't match 20+20GB. Nor are you out of space. I'm uncertain what you're really asking here.

Comment: @vidarlo If I do ``df -h`` it says: ``/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   19G   18G  204M  99% /`` and also when I log into the machine it says: ``Usage of /: 93.7% of 18.57GB`` so the disk only has 20GB but in oVirt I have set the disk to 40GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't expanded the disk partition yet. This is the *first* step and for some reason you are trying to skip it (and another mandatory step).

```
Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda3  2101248 41940991 39839744  19G Linux filesystem
```

Use the `growpart` tool to expand the partition *safely*. Remember that it takes the block device and partition number as separate arguments.

```
sudo growpart /dev/sda 3
```

Install it if you don't already have it installed.

Once that is done you can move on to resizing the PV and then the LV.

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3

... the rest of what you were trying to do.
```